# Difference Aggregate Root/Entity

Tags: entity, domain-driven-design, domain-model, aggregateroot

I' struggling with this question : how to tel if a concept is an aggregate root or just an entity (that is part of an AR) ? :

- They both got Ids
- They both are composed by entities or value object

Maybe if I need to reference an entity in an other AR then I need to make it an AR : if somewhere on the app I need to link something to a particular order line, then order line will become an AR.

Or it's just in terms of lifecycle, but if it is, I don't see the point of having an entity inside an AR : it's just value object.

Or maybe it's because an entity can change of AR then I'll promote it as AR.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Udi Dahan](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/) blog post and comments below.

From a technical perspective, AR is a transactional boundary. In other words, a group of entities which should stay consistent all the time. Going extreme with this definition, AR doesn't even have to have an Id.

From a business perspective, it is a primary concept in your domain that is part of Ubiquitous language, whereas entities don't have to be.

For example for car selling companies, Car is an AR but engine, wheel, tires and so on are just entities. But if you extend your car selling company's software with a car manufacture capabilities, then: engine, tires, etc: would probably be AR on their own in that part of the software. So if you have a piece of software that sells cars and makes them, you would sometimes have different AR depending on a context. Some objects will be AR in one place and an entity in the other. DDD names this concept as a "bounded context" or a "domain".

I think your confusion comes with the lack of upfront design and not having those "bounded context" properly defined.

Answer (score 1):

Entities can be retrieved only from within AR, and can't be referenced from another ARs. So when you delete AR, garbage collector should also collect all entites/valuesobject in it.

I make an AR everything that I need to retrieve by one(by id). You said that both (entities and AR) got ids. If entities got global ids, that would mean that you would want to retrieve them by id, so they should be ARs too.

Example of entity can be a reply to a post. You want to retrieve one post (AR), but you don't retrieve replies by id, you get replies from post AR. But if you would like to rate a reply, delete it, edit or something, then it will probably become an AR, because you will want to retrieve it without first retrieving post (and other replies with it, which would be an overhead).

Try to create small ARs (without big entity tree inside). When you want to reference AR from another AR, then do it by VO id, in example `FooAggregateId(1)`. Don't make reference to AR object, otherwise you would have to load a lot of ARs all at once, or use lazy loading.